Are chord inversions determined solely by the lowest note, even in a broken chord?

Example: Key signature of Bb Major, an F dominant 7th chord
Given a chord where the lowest note is the root but a non-root degree is played first, is it considered a root chord since the lowest note is given precedence, or is it considered an inversion since the inversion quality was first heard by the listener

Please, a picture with clef and key signatures!  Way too much work - and hard to infer correctly- without that!  We might be able to guess 2 violins, viola, soprano, bass ...  but not for sure

Title and composer would also be of value.

In general, yes, the lowest note, even in broken chords, and even if not the first note. However, there is some conceptual wiggle room. Since analysis is, in part, interpretive, one could imagine a situation in which a single chord in considered to sound twice — once in root position and once in inversion, or vice versa.
But in a situation where an entire passage is interpreted as a single chord, then it's solely the lowest chord tone.

A broken chord is still a chord. An arpeggio is an example of a broken chord.
A 'rule' has been made which states that any chord will have either root position or inversion. And the criterion here is simply the lowest note played. Otherwise there would be no way of labelling chords. And labelling is something humans love to do!
So, any chord at all will be labelled according to which of its notes is lowest.
